# Why I have a HAproxy error 503 while web servers are up and running?

Tags: haproxy

3 months ago I configured my HAproxy to balance 2 Apache webservers. Since then everything is up and running. Today I woke up seeing a HAproxy 503 error. When I checked the its web stats I saw the webservers marked as L7STS/500 (internal server error). Ironically every webserver is up and running, even the website is accessible when you browse both webserver IPs, so I really have no idea what's happening here. I even shutdown both webservers and when I browse www.myurl.com (now passing through HAproxy) I still see "503 Service Unavailable" (with webservers ON or OFF).

Not even with a restart (which occurs perfectly) this seems to get fixed.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

--
EDIT: The website uses Yii Framework. Yii has a "runtime/" directory which needs to have write permissions. The 500 error was because that directory was missing permission due to some file updates through FTP. Guess I have to work on sticky sessions in order to permanently fix this.

Comment: Check the apache access logs for the HAproxy health checks, apparently HAproxy is receiving HTTP status 500 in response to its checks. Are you checking an URL that doesn't work anymore but isn't used anymore either (which is why you don't see any problems when viewing your site)?